# Call controller of another directive in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I refer to directive's controller function from $apply in another directive of the same element? Example:

```
<myelement hint="myelement.controller.getMe()">hoverMe</myelement>

app.directive("myelement", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.getMe = function () {
                return "me";
            };
        }
    }
});

app.directive("hint", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: function ($rootScope) {
          this.showHint = function (getMsg) {
            alert($rootScope.$apply(getMsg)); //what should be written here?
          }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
              controller.showHint(attrs.hint);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Sources: http://plnkr.co/edit/9qth9N?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use require (read more about it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)).

```js
app.directive("hint", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: ["myelement", "hint"],
    controller: function ($scope) {
      this.showHint = function (msg) {
        alert($scope.$apply(msg)); //what should be written here?
      }
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        var myElementController = ctrls[0],
            hintController = ctrls[1];

        element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
          hintController.showHint(myElementController.getMsg());
        });
    }
  }
});
```

---

**UPDATE (about making Hint universal, see comments below)**

To make Hint directive universal, than you could use the $scope as the medium between them.

```js
app.directive("myelement", function () {
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.getMe = function () {
            return "me";
        };
    }
 }
});
```

```
<myelement hint="getMe()">hoverMe</myelement>
```

The only change is that the `getMe` message is not setted in the controller (`this.getMe`) but in the $scope (`$scope.getMe`).

Comment: I thought about require, but in my case `hint` should be a universal directive that can be applied to any other directive, the only thing it should know is what function to call to get the result

Comment: Updated the answer to address this requirement. As an alternative, you could also require `hint` at `myelement` and expose a hint API to change the message. I prefer the way I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Just a quick fix, you shouldn't be using `$rootScope` at hint directive, it should be `$scope`.